# How do you get permission to save rcS after setting UTC=no?

Tags: gedit, time

I am a first time user of Ubuntu. I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 dual boot with Windows. Ubuntu is screwing up the Windows clock. I looked this up and found the following lines to use:

- `gedit /etc/default/rcS` (in Terminal)
- `UTC=no` (in edit tool)

However, the `rcS` file will not save. The editing tool won't let me to save it. The editing program says I do not have permission. I am a noob. If there is a clear guide on how to get permission to edit and save `rcS`, step by step with actual command lines if possible, please direct me to it. If there is a very quick way to get permission to edit this file prior to editing, please let me know.

Comment: Can't modern versions of Windows finally cope with UTC in the hardware clock? Windows's insistence on a timezone-dependent clock is annoying when you travel between timezones or have a computer that's not turned off during DST changes.

Answer (score 5):

System files cannot be edited by users directly. They belong to the [root user](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_user). One way to run gedit as root is to invoke it as root:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/rcS
```

See also [Gedit command line tips](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/gedit#Command_Line_Tips) and [Graphical sudo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo) in the Ubuntu community documentation.

By the way, note that it's `rcS` (with a capital `S`) and `UTC=no` (with `UTC` in uppercase). Under Linux, unlike under Windows, file names and variable names are case-sensitive.

Comment: Thanks both. I will look into changing Windows as well as learning more about accessing root user. I preferred knowing how to manipulate Ubuntu, so this answer was much appreciated.